# How to solve this unusual system of equations?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to assign a numerical value to commodities exchanged in a barter system. My first idea was to set up a system of equations: if `foo` is exchanged for `bar` and `baz`, then `foo = bar + baz`. The problem is that the value of `foo` is not defined, so it could be exchanged for just `bar` immediately after being exchanged for `bar + baz`.

Is there a way to find some kind of average value of each commodity in a system like this?

Answer (score 0):

Since this seems to be an ongoing process of exchange we should introduce a time variable and treat the commodities as functions from time to $\mathbb{R}^+$ (assuming they cannot be negatively valued). For simplicity we can take time to be discrete, $t_0<t_1<\cdots$. In this case $foo(t_0)=bar(t_0)+baz(t_0)$ and $foo(t_1)=bar(t_1)$. Then the average price over $n$ times can be taken as a simple average.